# How to call a random value from an array in a dictionary? (Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript, dictionary, discord.js

I have a dictionary, let's say:

```
var array1 = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"];
var array2 = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"];

var dict = {"this":array1,"that":array2};
```

How do I call a random value within the array from the dictionary given that I have chosen a key?

e.g.

```
dict["this"] // Should return a random value from array rather than all values
```

I have tried using Math.random to get a random index number, which kind of works, but when using it, it always return the same value, which implies that the random number generator used for the index only runs once and does not update, resulting in giving the same value from the array every time unless I restart the code.

```
var array1 = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]; // array1
var array2 = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]; // array2

var randthis = Math.floor(array1.length * Math.random()); // random index for array 1
var randthat = Math.floor(array2.length * Math.random()); // random index for array 2

var dict = {"this":this[randthis],"that":that[randthat]};

msg.client.send(dict[this])
```

How should I make it so the random index will give me a different one every time? Or a different way to achieve this.
I know that I can achieve this in Python by importing random and using random.choice(dict[this])

Update:
I have the dictionary in a different module from my server module to not have too much code in the same module. So I am exporting the dictionary from dictionary.js and using it in actualcode.js (Don't think this matters, but going to state it just to make sure)

Update 2:

server.js:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client;
const cmd = require("./commands");

client.on("message", msg => {
  const prefix = '$'

  if (msg.author == client.user){
    return
  };

  if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix)){
    var command = msg.content.split(prefix).slice(1);
    msg.channel.send(cmd[command+"_cmd"]);
  }

});
```

commands.js:

```
var array1 = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]
var array2 = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]
var randindex = Math.floor(array1.length * Math.random())
var randindex2 = Math.floor(array2.length * Math.random())

var cmd = {"test_cmd":array1[randindex], "test2_cmd":array2[randindex2]}

module.exports = cmd
```

Comment: "this" is a keyword. do not use it as a variable name

Comment: Yes, it was a poor example, but in my code, the key and the variable have different names

Comment: You code *will* give you a different item each time. What makes you think it wouldn't? Run this a few times to see: https://jsfiddle.net/pamzjfk4/

Comment: I am running it on my discord bot, but for some reason, it always gives the same index even though it is supposed to be random. I did try running it about a hundred times just to get the same output hundred times, until I updated my code, which then the next index would repeat until updated again.

Comment: You might be better showing your *actual code* rather than what you think is the issue. It might be you're just doing something simple wrong. This discord bot seems to have no problem using random in js: https://github.com/Tony120914/Beldum-Bot/blob/master/js/commands/8ball.js

Comment: I have updated and put the actual code in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the same result every time is `commands.js` is only interpreted once, when you first load the file into `server.js`.

The way to "fix" this is to export a *function* in commands, and execute that function as you need it:

```
function execCmd() {
    var array1 = ["value1", "value 2", "value 3"]
    var randindex = Math.floor(array1.length * Math.random())

    return {"test_cmd":array1[randindex]}
}

module.exports = execCmd;
```

And

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client;
const cmd = require("./commands");

client.on("message", msg => {
  const prefix = '$'

  if (msg.author == client.user){
    return
  };

  if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix)){
    var command = msg.content.split(prefix).slice(1);
    var rndDict = cmd();
    msg.channel.send(rndDict[command+"_cmd"]);
  }

});
```

Comment: does this also work for dictionary with multiple keys?

Comment: The number of keys is irrelevant. It is the execution of javascript you're not understanding.

Comment: So if I have more keys I just add them to return?

Comment: Anyways, this solved my problem. Thank you very much.